# Pip requirements installation fails in Travis due to idna version conflict

Tags: python, pip, travis-ci

[One of my Travis build tests](https://travis-ci.com/github/zobayer1/elastic-migrate/jobs/487243062) have started to fail with the following error:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested idna==3.1
    requests 2.25.1 depends on idna<3 and >=2.5
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

However, this runs fine on my local machine. For example:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\elastic-migrate>tox -e py38
GLOB sdist-make: C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\elastic-migrate\setup.py
py38 create: C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\elastic-migrate\.tox\py38
py38 installdeps: -rrequirements.txt
py38 inst: C:\Users\Asus\PycharmProjects\elastic-migrate\.tox\.tmp\package\1\elastic-migrate-0.1.0.dev126+g8e5eb23.zip
py38 installed: appdirs==1.4.4,atomicwrites==1.4.0,attrs==20.3.0,certifi==2020.12.5,cfgv==3.2.0,chardet==4.0.0,click==7.1.2,click-log==0.3.2,codecov==2.1.11,colorama==0.4.4,coverage==5.3.1,distlib==0.3.1,elastic-migrate @ file:///C:/Us
ers/Asus/PycharmProjects/elastic-migrate/.tox/.tmp/package/1/elastic-migrate-0.1.0.dev126%2Bg8e5eb23.zip,filelock==3.0.12,flake8==3.8.4,identify==1.5.10,idna==2.10,importlib-metadata==3.3.0,iniconfig==1.1.1,jsonschema==3.2.0,mccabe==0.
6.1,more-itertools==8.6.0,nodeenv==1.5.0,packaging==20.8,pluggy==0.13.1,pre-commit==2.9.3,py==1.10.0,pycodestyle==2.6.0,pyfakefs==4.3.3,pyflakes==2.2.0,pyparsing==2.4.7,pyrsistent==0.17.3,pytest==6.2.1,pytest-cov==2.10.1,pytest-mock==3
.4.0,PyYAML==5.3.1,requests==2.25.1,requests-mock==1.8.0,setuptools-scm==5.0.1,six==1.15.0,SQLAlchemy==1.3.22,toml==0.10.2,tox==3.20.1,urllib3==1.26.2,validator-collection==1.5.0,virtualenv==20.2.2,wcwidth==0.2.5,zipp==3.4.0
py38 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='473'
```

For reference:

- My [.travis.yml](https://github.com/zobayer1/elastic-migrate/blob/master/.travis.yml) file
- My [tox.ini](https://github.com/zobayer1/elastic-migrate/blob/master/tox.ini) file

This has started happening since I've tried to add python 3.9 support to the project, and [pyup](https://pyup.io/) has upgraded the dependencies subsequently. As I've dug about it a little, I've found that there are others facing [the same issues](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5710). However, I am unable to find a satisfactory way to go about it. What is the recommended way to handle tox environment dependencies better? One `requirements.txt` file doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, **pip** didn't have a proper dependency resolver. So, if you asked it to install a package without any version flag, you’d be getting the newest version of the package, even if it conflicts with other packages that you had already installed.

However, with **pip 20.3**, this changes, and now **pip** has a stricter dependency resolver. Pip will now complain if any of your sub-dependencies are incompatible.

As a quick fix, you can pin your **idna** version in your `requirements.txt` to **2.05**. As a longer-term solution, you can adopt a tool like [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) where you will be able to pin your top-level dependencies in a `requirements.in` file and run a `pip-compile` command to generate the `requirements.txt` file. This way there will be an explicit delineation between the top-level dependencies and the sub-dependencies. Also, the tool will resolve the sub-dependency conflicts for you.

Comment: I had to downgrade two dependencies in order to fix this: `idna==2.05 # pyup: ignore` and `importlib-metadata==2.1.1;python_version<'3.8' # pyup: ignore`. For now, this will have to do. Tanks for linking pip-tools, I will definitely take a look at that.